# Add/Synchronize Pictures/Folder to iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud, finder

I recently acquired a new macbook and I want to synchronize the "Pictures" and "Movies" folders with iCloud.

-I don't know how- but I managed to do it on my other macbook after acquiring it, but I haven't been able to do it on my new laptop.

On both computers I added iCloud Drive:
[image]

It looks like this on my old computer:

('Images' and 'Bureau' are the french names for the 'Pictures' and 'Desktop', respectively)

[image]

This is how it looks like on my new computer:

[image]

It works just as I wanted for Desktop, but I can't add 'Pictures' to iCloud for my new computer, and 'Documents' isn't visible anymore in  `user/`  even though the terminal says it is there:

```
Last login: Fri Jun 11 00:07:54 on ttys000[![enter image description here][3]][3]
(base) ➜  ~ cd Documents 
(base) ➜  Documents pwd 
/Users/[user]/Documents
(base) ➜  Documents cd ..
(base) ➜  ~ ls
Applications Documents    Library      Music        Public
Desktop      Downloads    Movies       Pictures
```

Do you have any idea of what I have to do to add new folders to iCloud, and make 'Documents' visible again ?